# Missing template with format js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails project I want to open a modal box (face box) via ajax. My code in the index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'Anmelden', fb_login_path, :remote => true %>
```

This throws me the error:

> Missing template facebox/fb_login, application/fb_login with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb, :coffee]}. Searched in: ...

That is right because my template is a js.erb-file. I read somewhere that I have to add in my controller:

**FaceboxController:**

```
  def fb_login
    respond_to do | format |
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Doing this I am getting the error:

> Started GET "/facebox/fb_login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-05 18:09:46 +0100
>   Processing by FaceboxController#fb_login as HTML
>   Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

This is weird because last week everything worked. In the meantime - as far as I remember - I didn't change a thing. But now I am getting this error.

I know this sounds weird but I hope that someone can help me.

Thanks!
Lars

EDIT

This ist my fb_login.js.erb-Code:

```
$.facebox('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'devise/sessions/new') %>')
```

EDIT 2

Here is the output for rake routes

> fb_login        /facebox/fb_login(.:format)        facebox#fb_login

and routes.rb:

```
 match '/facebox/fb_login' => 'facebox#fb_login', :as => :fb_login
```

Perhaps that helps

Comment: Please post your `fb_login.js.erb` template code

Comment: No ideas? Shall I post some more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting 'rails' in the gem file to '3.2.20' and running 'bundle update rails' finally worked for me.